# publish as3 ios app with many files

Tags: actionscript-3

I am developing an app in AS3 with a folder with 35000 files. By publishing gives me memory error, what you think of suggestion? You could compress and then decompress when installing to prevent this from happening?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How large are the files? Even at 1kb each, that is ~35MB. AIR is ~9.5MB as 4.0. Average app is another 3-5MB. Max binary size on the iTunes store is 60MB. You might be approaching that max. Could you post the full error? What are the files for? Could they be moved to a remote server? We really cannot help you without further details.

Comment: Sorry for not giving more details. 
The app uses a database of sounds in mp3 files are about 35,000 and occupy about 300Mb. 
Sure, crossed my mind or pass it to a remote server and then download them in Zip and unzip, but does not do this as well. 
If I generate the app folder without files done correctly, once you put it gives this error:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:Java heap space

Comment: As Josh said - there is an app max size, which you obviously exceed. Read carefully the guidelines from Apple.
And just a friendly memo - how do you imagine Apple to host >300mb apps, and let you download them via smartphone?

Comment: And it could make the application of 30Mb data file and hang it on a server for later download zip and unzip? I am new to AS3, how could I do? 
thank you very much

Comment: Yeah, you definitely cannot do this. Even if you didn't hit a memory error, you're going to get rejected, *for sure*, by Apple. They won't even review your app, it will be automatically rejected by the system. They may not even allow you to upload it. You **must** offload these files to a server and load them on-demand. You should never have files loaded into memory unless they are being used (or saved for use soon) anyway

Comment: You shouldn't even download them all at once, @Lolillo67. You should set up a server which will allow you to load them, one at a time, as they are needed. It's the only way to properly do it